# C program to adjust the carry in an integer array

Tags: arrays, c

I want to write a C program to adjust the carry in an integer array (i.e. convert the 2 digit number into a single-digit and add the carry to the next number).

For example -

> Array - 6 12 3 15 7
> Answer: 7 2 4 5 7

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int array[6]={6,22,3,15,7};
    int array2[2];
    int i;
    printf("%d\n",array[1]);        
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(array[i]>10){
            array2[i]=array[i];
            printf("Value at %d element of array is: %d \n",i,array2[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So far I have been able to write a program that just finds out double-digit numbers in the array.
I'm relatively new to C and don't know much about how to perform arithmetic operations **in** arrays.

Help me please!!

Comment: so you want carry to be added to previous elemet? what if the starting element is double digit, ie `{11,2}`?

Comment: @sittsering Yes. If the first element is double-digit, then the 1 at tens place in 11 will just be ignored.

Comment: okay, so it will be {1,2} ?

Comment: @sittsering Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since we are adding the carry to previous element, we should start in reverse order.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[5] = {6,22,3,15,7};
    for(i=4;i>0;i--)
    {
        if(a[i]>9)
        {
            int rem = a[i]%10;
            int carry = a[i]/10;
            a[i] = rem;
            a[i-1] = a[i-1] + carry;
        }
    }
    if(a[0]>9)
        a[0] = a[0]%10;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not working completely. 

Here is the output when I printed a[i-1]:

```7 15 4 22 8```

Comment: value of 6 and 3 got incremented but instead of ```15``` it should ```5``` and instead of ```22``` it should be ```2```. Can you help me? 

You have been a lot of help. Thanks

Comment: @AdvaitDandekar done fixing. <https://onlinegdb.com/IW7v8LPRG>